# BASH script: declare a variable inside CASE statement to use globally

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

```
case $location in
    ColocationOne) 
        # Define MOSES LAKE workerarray
        server[0]=serverone
        server[1]=servertwo
esac

echo ${server[0]}
```

How do I get this to echo: `serverone` 
?

Comment: @Peschke I am echoing `${server[0]}` after my initial edit.  The first was a typo.  I am just trying to use a variable that I declared inside the `case` statement from outside the case statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `location` to the string `ColocationOne`:

```
#!/bin/bash

location=ColocationOne

case $location in
    ColocationOne) 
        # Define MOSES LAKE workerarray
        server[0]=serverone
        server[1]=servertwo
        # or:  server=( serverone servertwo )
esac

echo "${server[0]}"
```

This script would print `serverone`.

Comment: yes you are correct.  My actual script has the quotes.  My actual script referenced server[1].  My actual script had server[1] commented out.  stone212 is very tired.  Thank you.